# TFS 2015 Branching and Merging

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging, branching-strategy

I am using TFS 2015 and struggling with a branching model. below is what I am trying to achieve:

Current we have a "Dev" Branch from which we take a new "Feature" branch for every new sprint story. We complete the coding and then merge back into the "Dev" branch. This bit is working ok.

But now I have created a "QA" branch off "Dev" branch and want to apply the following coding/branching flow:

"Dev" branches to --> "Feature" branch --> Then merges into "QA" branch.

Now when I tried to merge from "Feature" branch to "QA" branch, I got the baseless merge issue with no relationship defined.

Surely, both the "Feature" branch and "QA" branch both branched from "Dev" branch so I should be able to do a normal merge.

So my question is, what am I missing or doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, your Dev branch hierarchy is like below:

[image]

There is no direct relationship between Feature branch and QA branch, so if you want to merge between Feature branch and QA branch, a baseless merge will be performed.

If you want to use this hierarchy, you can first merge from Feature branch to Dev branch, then merge from Dev branch to QA branch.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So is my branching strategy flawed or is it , with your suggestion added, an acceptable approach to use? Thanks

Comment: You may have a Main branch, which is the junction branch between development and release branches, representing a stable snapshot of the product that can be shared with QA team. Then you can branch from Main to Dev and QA. Check Branching strategies: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/branching-strategies-with-tfvc